# Is running a Vba script or Macro in Excel thread safe

Tags: excel, multithreading, vba, macros

Just a general question but would like to know if I run vba scripts or Macros in Excel are they considered to be thread safe?

Comment: I did exactly that with Excel 2003 once.  I made a VBA module that created a separate thread to talk to the server and then sent the data to excel with a custom windows message so that the cells could be updated every two seconds.  And it worked.  For a while.  Every so often Excel would crash for no reason - the cells could be updating for several minutes and then BLAM! it would crash.  So not with Excel 2003 anyway.

Comment: Yes sounds familiar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I have [found](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/from-vba-to-c-part-9-the-additional-types-of-udf-you-can-create-in-an-xll/):

> In Excel 2007 and later on a multi-core PC this can speed up execution significantly. VBA functions cannot be made thread-safe.

But in the end, I suspect it'll come down to how well written the code actually is.

Comment: To an extent but when a function is thread safe in C then its exactly that. Their does not seem to be any guarantee with vba functions